# makeText didnt work on my first game in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created my first math game, all works fine but makeText didnt work. When I click on answer nothing happened don't get `"Well Done!"` or `"Sorry that's wrong"`.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class GameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    int correctAnswer;
    Button buttonObjectChoice1;
    Button buttonObjectChoice2;
    Button buttonObjectChoice3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);



//ovde inicijalizujem sve varijable


        int partA = 9;
        int partB = 9;
        int correctAnswer = partA * partB;
        int wrongAnswer1 = correctAnswer + 1;
        int wrongAnswer2 = correctAnswer - 1;

    /*ovde povezujem  objekte sa odgovarajucim UI-em*/


        TextView textObjectPartA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPartA);
        TextView textObjectPartB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPartB);
        Button buttonObjectChoice1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
        Button buttonObjectChoice2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);
        Button buttonObjectChoice3 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);



/*sada cu koristiti setText metodu za moje nove objekte
da pokazem vrednost na Ui dizajnu.
Just like when we output to the console in the exercise -
Expressions in Java, only now we use setText method
to put the values in our variables onto the actual UI. */


        textObjectPartA.setText("" + partA);
        textObjectPartB.setText("" + partB);


//which button receives which answer, at this stage is arbitrary.


        buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + correctAnswer);
        buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
        buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);



    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


//declare a new int to be used in all the cases


        int answerGiven=0;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonChoice1:


//initialize a new int with the value contained in buttonObjectChoice1
//Remember we put it there ourselves previously


                answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" +  buttonObjectChoice1.getText());


//is it the right answer?



                if(answerGiven==correctAnswer)
                {//yay it's the right answer
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Well done!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{



//uh oh!



                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry that's wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.buttonChoice2:


//same as previous case but using the next button


                answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" +  buttonObjectChoice2.getText());
                if(answerGiven==correctAnswer) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Well done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry that's wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonChoice3:

                //same as previous case but using the next button
                answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" +  buttonObjectChoice3.getText());
                if(answerGiven==correctAnswer) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Well done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry that's wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }




    }



}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Bodin! Please try to type in clear English (ie, not l33t speak) to maximise your chance of getting your question answered. Have you tried distilling the problem to the minimal amount of code to replicate the problem?

Comment: Thank you for edit sugest. Im rookie here and in programing, so i dont know how to distilling the prob to the minimial amount of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why this is not working. Since you are new to Android, I will also give you a few tips.

First off, you have accidentally defined 2 Button objects for each of your buttons. First you define them as member variables at the top of the Activity:

```
Button buttonObjectChoice1;
Button buttonObjectChoice2;
Button buttonObjectChoice3;
```

Then you define them as local variables inside onCreate():

```
    Button buttonObjectChoice1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
    Button buttonObjectChoice2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);
    Button buttonObjectChoice3 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);
```

You should only have your buttons as member OR local variables, not both.  To keep them as member variables only, set their ids this way:

```
    buttonObjectChoice1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
    buttonObjectChoice2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);
    buttonObjectChoice3 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);
```

When you notice that your Toast is not being displayed, your first order of business should be to check that your OnClick() method is actually being called at all.  You can do this by putting a breakpoint on the first line of OnClick(), or by putting in a log statement as the first line of OnClick(). Click your button, and if your log never shows up, you now know it is an issue with your OnClick setup, not the Toasts.

Having your activity implement `View.OnClickListener` is not enough for the `OnClick` method to work properly. You also need to attach this listener to each view item you care to "listen" to. You can do this after you call `findViewById()` for each of the buttons:

```
    buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonObjectChoice2.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonObjectChoice3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

You pass in `this` because your current Activity is the one that defines the listener.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kio, you rock!!!! Now  got message "Sorry wrong answer", but this pop up for every answer. :/  Android Studi said my variable _answerGiven_  initializer '0' is redundant. What is wrong? My  variable _answergiven_ or swith method?

Comment: After `findViewById` i put `this` for every button.                  `buttonObjectChoice1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(this);             buttonObjectChoice2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);        buttonObjectChoice2.setOnClickListener(this);              buttonObjectChoice3 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);
buttonObjectChoice3.setOnClickListener(this); `

Comment: You're welcome! Very glad I could help. I suggest you put a bunch of log statements in your code, and print out values of important variables throughout your code. This will help you understand why exactly you always get "sorry wrong answer".  Here is some information on creating log statements in Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html  If you still cannot solve the issue, you should open a new Stack Overflow question.

Comment: You help me a lot. I solve problem, now all works fine. Problem is in `onCreat` when i define `correctAnswer` i put `int` before it, when delete `int` all works fine. :D thanks again